# Two different subdomains in one Next.js routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

I want to build a new platform using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) ([React.js](https://reactjs.org/) and [React-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)). There will be a two spaces. One front-end for users and one for the owner to allow them manage all users. I want to split both areas into two subdomains, like this:

front.domain.com
panel.domain.com

React-router does not support sub-domain routing, so I tried to find another approach. I found something like that, but I am not sure that this is what I want. Please advice.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path="/" render={props => {
    const [subdomain] = window.location.hostname.split('.');
    if (subdomain === 'panel') return <PanelLayout {...props}/>;
    return <FrontLayout {...props}/>;
  }}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: When you are using next, there is no need for react-router, it has built-in router.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't split 1 Next.js app between sub-domains for several reasons.
From an experience, I had a similar requirement (3 areas) I started with one app split into 3 (using sub paths)

1. Assets (css, js libs) leaks between "areas".
2. one big app with 3 areas means, each change will require re-deploy all the areas (one big deployable)
3. Build time, to build 3 areas will be much longer.
4. Each area may introduce different requirement, such as, UI components for admin area, but custom ui components for the "front" area, Auth, translations and many more

Ended up with 3 separate Next.js apps which managed inside yarn workspaces and get deployed by a specific area.

After I've explained my experience, you can achieve a setup with a reverse-proxy such as [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) to map sub-domain to subpath in your next app.

Let's say you have 3 areas, front, admin, users.

`www.domain.com/some-page` => should be mapped to `localhost:3000/front/some-page`.
`users.domain.com/some-page` => should be mapped to `localhost:3000/users/some-page`.
`admin.domain.com/some-page` => should be mapped to `localhost:3000/admin/some-page`.

```
// www.domain.com.conf 

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    root         html;
 
    location / {
      proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3000/front/; // <-- the last slash is important
    }

  }
```

```
// users.domain.com.conf

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  users.domain.com;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    root         html;
 
    location / {
      proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/; // <-- the last slash is important
    }

  }
```

**Pay attention**

1. you will need to rewrite **static** assets as well.

Comment: Splitting it into 2 separate apps (e.g. `admin` and `front`) will make it easier to manage the code-base but you'll also lose the user login state. For example, if a user logs into the `admin` and you need to be aware of it on the `front` app it, this functionality would be harder to a achieve and requires more complex solution.

Comment: It is a matter of trade-offs, it depends on what is auth solution, you can save the admin token on a **domain** cookie, which will be accessible in the front as well

Comment: Thanks for the hint about **domain cookie**, I wasn't aware that you can share the auth cookie among subdomains of same root. It makes the things much easier.

Comment: @felixmosh Can you please give an example code for "rewrite static assets"

Comment: @NitinSinghNaruka, give me an example of static asset path

Comment: @felixmosh this is "_next/static/"

Comment: It should be handled by next's internal server (which we proxied to)

Answer (score 11):

I manage to create subdomains using a custom express server. This is a blank app with no assets, I haven't tried this yet on a real app with assets (CSS, images, etc)

I have the following pages folder structure:

```
pages/
├── admin/
│   ├── index.js
│   └── sample-page.js
└── member/
    ├── index.js
    └── accounts/
        └── dashboard.js
```

When you are using `next dev` which is the default. This will produce the following routes:

- http://lvh.me:3000/admin
- http://lvh.me:3000/admin/sample-page
- http://lvh.me:3000/member
- http://lvh.me:3000/member/accounts/dashboard

But using the custom `server.js` file and running our dev server using `node server.js` this will produce the following routes:

- http://admin.lvh.me:3000
- http://admin.lvh.me:3000/sample-page
- http://lvh.me:3000
- http://lvh.me:3000/accounts/dashboard

The content of our `server.js` file:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const vhost = require('vhost')

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const mainServer = express()
  const adminServer = express()
  const memberServer = express()

  adminServer.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/admin', req.query)
  })

  adminServer.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, `/admin${req.path}`, req.query)
  })

  adminServer.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  memberServer.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/member', req.query)
  })

  memberServer.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, `/member${req.path}`, req.query)
  })

  memberServer.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  mainServer.use(vhost('admin.lvh.me', adminServer))
  mainServer.use(vhost('lvh.me', memberServer))
  mainServer.use(vhost('www.lvh.me', memberServer))
  mainServer.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err

    console.log(`> Ready on http://lvh.me:${port}`)
  })
})
```

See the repo to see this in action.

Repo: https://github.com/dcangulo/nextjs-subdomain-example

Answer (score 10):

Here’s an example of hosting **multiple domains on the same Next.js site** (while maintaining **multiple languages** and static site generation/SSG), using Next.js’ i18n system:

https://github.com/tomsoderlund/nextjs-multi-domain-locale

Vercel now supports **wildcard domains** (*.mysite.com) which is cool!

Comment: To me this is the best, easiest solution. You don't need to change your server, whether it's NGINX or Express. NextJS actually does support this through Locales, as is mentioned. Thanks @Tom

Comment: It's literally supported, you just have to use domain names as locales https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing

Answer (score 3):

As of today you should be able to achieve this with Vercel's Next.js multi-tenancy middleware. To read more about it have a look here https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-multi-tenant-application

Side note: Middleware is available from Next.js's version 12 and up.

Answer (score 1):

If you host on Vercel now, you can use their wildcard subdomains and have your client-side React code mount the component tree relevant to the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You check to see if the `pathname` from Next's router starts with a pre-defined list of allowed sub-paths

e.g.

```
const subdomainPaths = {
  request: '/request',
  company: '/company',
};

const isSubdomainRoute = () => {
  const paths = Object.values(subdomainPaths).filter((path) => router.pathname.startsWith(path));
  return !!paths.length;
};

if (window.location.host.includes('subdomain.mysite') && !isSubdomainRoute()) {
  // show 404 or redirect somewhere else
  return <div>404 - not found</div>;
}
```

Full example:

```
export const isSSR = typeof window === 'undefined';

export default function App(props: Props) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;
  const router = useRouter();

  const subdomainPaths = {
    request: '/request',
    company: '/company',
  };

  const isSubdomainRoute = () => {
    const paths = Object.values(subdomainPaths).filter((path) => router.pathname.startsWith(path));
    return !!paths.length;
  };

  if (!isSSR) {
    if (window.location.host.includes('subdomain.mysite') && !isSubdomainRoute()) {
      // show 404 or redirect somewhere else
      return <div>404 - not found</div>;
    }
  }

  // otherwise fallthrough to the normal Next.js return

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>My Site</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      </Head>
      <AllTheProviders>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </AllTheProviders>
    </>
  );
}
```