# Multiple Next.js apps on one single server with different subdomains

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, server, next.js

I did a lot of search on this topic but still don't know a good solution for my problem. So I thought maybe someone can guide me into this.

### About the project

We're basically planning to build a shop builder, each shop (website) has the same theme, but its content, which is fetched from an API source, differs from one to another.
So we are going to have a single code base for our front-end application (Next.js app) which renders different pages based on the **props** we pass to its **components**. The only way we can tell our app to render different content is by using **subdomains**. Consider the following component:

```
const ProductList = () => {
    const { data } = useSWR(
        "http://example.api/products?subdomain=abc123",
        fetcher
    );

    return (
        <ul>
            {data?.map((product) => (
                <ProductCard product={product} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
};
```

Since Next.js is using **node.js** behind the scene:

My question is, how can I run multiple instances of Next.js processes on a single server, so that we can reduce the costs?

I really appreciate every little help from the community. Thank you for your time. I would be glad to explain it more if you need more details about the problem.

Comment: Have you tried pm2? You can run multiple instances of node apps and reverse proxy each one through nginx server blocks or apache virtualhosts

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, does pm2 have limits? or I can run as many instances as I want as long as I my server can handle it.

Comment: I don't believe it has a limit on how many processes it can run, the only limitation should be the amount of RAM you assign to it. You can google it to find more info about the software.

Comment: Some related info - [link1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12848#discussioncomment-680225), [2 subdomains in single app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248827/two-different-subdomains-in-one-next-js-routing), [multi zones in nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/multi-zones)